# Is there a way to populate a form with a querystring?

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, query-string

As said in the title , is there a way populate a form with a queystring ?

I have a django form with 2 fields:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And a querystring like

```
subject=this&message=that
```

Is there a way to populate the form without manually parsing the querystring ?
The querystring is a saved(in db) form using jquery's `.serialize()`.

I am using django 1.5

EDIT:

Doing something like:

```
form = Myform(my_model.querystring)
```

gives me a form with good initial data but no cleaned_data

Comment: Why not just parse it? It's only 2 or 3 lines of code.

Comment: your title is asking for a yes or no answer, i doubt that's really what you want. If it is, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end had to do this for it to work.

```
from django.http import QueryDict
form = Myform(QueryDict(my_model.querystring).dict())
```

The .dict() did the trick, using a raw QueryDict did not work, same thing for `initial=QueryDict().dict()`

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating a form is exactly the same whether you use POST data or GET data. In this case you just need to do `form = MyForm(request.GET)`.

Comment: the querystring comes from a db model, passing it as the first argument has a strange behaviour, form.fields['subject'].initial works but not form.cleaned_data['subject'] after calling form.is_valid() (return True) cleaned_data is empty

Comment: I can't imagine why you're saving a raw query string in the db, that seems a very odd thing to do. But you could use it to instantiate a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), which is what Django does with request data anyway, and then pass that to the form.

Comment: I am already doing it but it does not help, it still behaves the same way, the reason for me saving the query string in db is to enable users to save their search in a big complex form

Comment: Another case where this happens is when an AJAX submit via $('form').serialize() populates only request.body with the querystring.  In this case neither request.GET nor request.POST is available.